# The structure of the loaded circuit in Thevenin's theorem

Tags: circuit-analysis

If the load in Thevenin's theorem happens to be a circuit instead of a single resistor, must this loaded circut contain only resistors or may it contain also voltage or current sources, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have any circuit named X which contains voltage sources, current sources, resistors, capacitors, inductors and linear amplifiers, but absolutely no parts where currents and voltages depend on each other obeying some non-linear equation.

Take any 2 nodes of X, say A and B. Thevenin equivalent of X in relative with nodes A and B contains a voltage source and a series impedance, which both may depend on frequency or be presented in s-domain with Laplace transforms.

The Thevenin equivalent of X in relative with nodes A and B is the same, no matter what load you are going to connect between A and B. You can connect as well a single resistor or a more complex circuit which can contain anything. Only be sure that no other connections are made between X and your load.

Answer (score 1):

It may contain anything, however, the first circuit must be linear.